# Apply webkit blur filter to parent only? ( Disable filter on child! )

Tags: filter, webkit, tumblr

I am not very experienced with coding as I've just started not too long ago, and am currently working on a Tumblr theme for here; http://heavenlyblue-theme.tumblr.com/ and I would like to make it so hovering over the posts will reveal the permalink and blur the entry only ( I want the permalink to be the focus ).

I'm not really sure how to go about doing such a thing, as applying the filter to the entry on hover makes it apply to the permalink.

I'm using Chrome atm.

```
#content .entry {


background-color: {color:COLOR06};

width: 500px;

margin: 0px 20px 20px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 50px;

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;  
position: relative;


}
```

.entry:hover {

```
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
```

}

.perma {

```
position: absolute;
width: 460px;
background-color: #fff;

height: auto;
padding: 20px;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);

opacity:0;
```

}

.entry:hover .perma {

```
opacity:1;
```

}

The HTML looks like this.

```
 <div class="entry">
    <div class="perma">

    <center>&#9654; <a href="{Permalink}">
    {NoteCountWithLabel}</a>

    &#9654; <a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>

    &#9654; <a href="{ReblogParentURL}"title="{ReblogParentName}">via</a> &#10010; <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootName}"> source</a>


    <a href="{ReblogURL}"><font size="3">&#8635;</font></a>


    </center>


    <div class="tags">{block:Tags}
    <a href="{TagURL}">&#10010; {Tag}</a>
    {/block:Tags}
    </div>


</div>
```

I've searched around and I see some similar questions, but I don't really understand the solutions or, rather, how to apply them to my code here. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `.entry:hover > :not(.perma) { -webkit-filter: blur(1px); }` and `.entry:hover .perma { opacity: 1; z-index: 1; }` should do the trick, I believe, from some playing on your site that I just did.

Comment: This has been covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586529/disable-blur-filter-on-child-containers