# Disable Blur filter on child containers

Tags: css, filter

So im working on a home page/cover page for a website and i have a parent container and a child container.

The parent container has a background image with a `blur(10px)` filter but the filter is also applying to the child container, which is what i dont want.

I have tried some solutions from other similar questions but none have helped or i might not be doing it right.

I tried setting the child container with `z-index: 9999` and the parent to `z-index: 0`. I just also found another solution that could work since we had the same setup but its confusing.

The solution was to add this line of code `background > :not(header) { webkit-filter: blur(10px); }`. `background` is the parent and `header` is the child. (nav will also not be blurred but i want to get one element working first).

I even tried to change the positions of the containers from `absolute` to `relative` and vise versa on each.

This is my html file (css and html are in same file).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "Candy";
    src: url('font/Candy.otf') format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "DancingScript";
    src: url('font/DancingScript.ttf') format("truetype");
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
background {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("images/cover_page.jpg") no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
background > :not(header) {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
header {
    font-face: "Candy";
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
nav {
    color: #FFF;
    font-face: "DancingScript";
    font-size: 25px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
header, nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<background>
    <header>Rustic Rentals</header>
    <nav>
       <ul>
            <li>Rentals</li>
            <li>Sales</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</background>
</body>
</html>
```

The result can be seen [here](http://rusticrentals.oldtreasuresfurniture.com/new_index.html).

Comment: there is no such `<background>` HTML tag

Comment: no there isnt, its HTML5, i can make up tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- there is no `background` HTML tag,
- when you are applying `filters` remember to not only use the `-webkit-`
- there is no `font-face` attribute to declare the font you are using, instead you should use `font-family`

With this in mind, a solution for your problem is creating a empty child `div` and applying the filter to that same empty `div` which must have a lower `z-index` then its siblings (as you already had)

Here is a snippet:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Candy";
  src: url('font/Candy.otf') format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "DancingScript";
  src: url('font/DancingScript.ttf') format("truetype");
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://rusticrentals.oldtreasuresfurniture.com/images/cover_page.jpg") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);}

header {
  font-family: "Candy";
  font-size: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
nav {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "DancingScript";
  font-size: 25px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
header,
nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <header>Rustic Rentals</header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Rentals</li>
      <li>Sales</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Comment: the `font-face` as attribute is a typo, idk what i was thinking. i also know about using `-moz-`, `-o-`, etc... i was just using `-webkit-` since im using chrome, after that i usually do the whole browser compatibility phase.

Comment: This helped you solving your problem?

Comment: ill give it a try tonight, i havent been able to work on the website all day.